# MYSQL OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions

Tags: mysql, .net, mono

I'm getting an error from OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions in my log, and I can't seem to find where this happens. I have no loss of data; when I have the logfactiory set to null, it breaks on no errors; I have set it to allow zero date, but that didn't help. I not sure how to debug this or get around it. It clogs up my logg with statements that I can't track.

This occurs on both linux and windows.

Doesn anyone have an idea how to get at this?

> ```
> OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. 
> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style) 
> at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) 
> at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ParseShortestXsdDateTime(String dateTimeStr) 
> at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Converters.DateTimeConverter.FromDbValue(Type fieldType, Object value) 
> at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.PopulateWithSqlReader[T](T objWithProperties, IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, IDataReader reader, Tuple`3[] indexCache, Object[] values)
> ```

UPDATE:

The logging occurs in the correct file set in the nlog config file, BUT for this exception only it does not conform to formatting in the layout set for NLOG (all other exceptions do!).

Layout string:
${longdate} ${machinename} ${logger} ${level} ${message} ${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED:${exception:format=type,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}}

UPDATE2 SOLVED:

So this was fun... Before I start to explain how I solved it I have to say that I have no idea why it writes in the correct log file, but ignore all formatting for logging errors - that be another dragon to slay for another time.

So the problem was that a varchar field in the mysql database had birthdate as string and the implicit conversion between DateTime in dotnet to string thre an error.

After changing the field to datetime in thet database the error went away.

Funny thing is that I hade to set minlevel to trace to get the error in context with its call to the database - but it still ignored all error formatting, had no stacktrace, no sql statement, and no line number associated with the error in the log.

Comment: It appears you have a value coming from the result of a query that is expected to be a date-time but cannot be parsed as such. You might need to log not just the details of an exception but the inner exception as well (recursively).

Comment: I have format for stacktrace, but this is all I get - that's why I'm stumped.

my nlog layout:
${machinename} ${logger} ${message} ${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=type,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that a varchar field in the mysql database had birthdate as string and the implicit conversion between DateTime in dotnet to string thre an error.

After changing the field to datetime in thet database the error went away.

Funny thing is that I had to set minlevel to trace to get the error in context with its call to the database - but it still ignored all error formatting, had no stacktrace, no sql statement, and no line number associated with the error in the log.